# How to use PIVOT keyword in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have one table in Postgres which has following columns:

```
processtransactionid bigserial,
TenantID uuid,
ProcessInstanceId bigint
attributename varchar(250),
attributevalue varchar(250),  
createddate timestamp,
queueid int
```

The `attributename` contains values like 'filename', 'documentstatus', 'batchImportdate', etc. and `attributevalue` columns contains corresponding values of the attribute, like `filename = abc.jpg, documentstatus ='Present' & batchImportdate='2019/08/26 12:57:51'`

I want output in the following way:

```
 ProcessInstanceId filename  documentstatus batchImportdate        queueid 
   6008            abc.jpg   Present        '2019/08/26 12:57:51'  2
   6008            abc.jpg   Absent         '2019/08/26 12:57:51'  3
```

grouping of the records to be done by `ProcessInstanceId, queueid`

I am able to create query in SQL Server using the `PIVOT` keyword but facing a problem in creating the same query in Postgres.

Could you please help me write the Postgres query?

Comment: PostgreSQL does not have the `PIVOT` keyword. Instead, you can use the `crosstab()` extension as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905). p.s. welcome to the forum! :-) p.p.s. In future, could you provide a fiddle with your sample data and your desired result as detailed in articles in my profile? For example, you could have given your working SQL Server query as the example of what you wanted to do?

Comment: You've been told that PostgreSQL doesn't have the `PIVOT` keyword. You've been given (a very detailed) outline of how to do this in PostgreSQL - Erwin Brandstetter is one of the top PG guys here. Now, if you can't get the query to run as you with, I suggest that you delete this question and repost it as (something like) `Have query working in MS SQL, how to get it to work in PostgreSQL?` and **include** the working MS query in a fiddle!